# Can SHOW TABLES be fired automatically by mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a lot of tables (> 50000), as a consequence the "SHOW TABLES" statement takes relatively long.

The code I am running does not contain the statement, but I still see it showing up with "show processlist" each time I run my script.

Is there any way mysql could execute the statement automatically ?

FYI:
The code is PHP running from the command line. It uses the adodb library to execute mysql statements. I have removed any instance of SHOW TABLES in the adodb code and replaced it with "blabla", but it still shows up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you're using a GUI interface it may automatically execute show tables... use command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

Even the CLI may call SHOW TABLES if you don't start it with -A.